# Two cplots in the same plot

Tags: r

I was wondering if it was possible to have two different cplots in the same plot.
For example this creates two different plots:

```
library("margins")
cplot(reg3, x="total_imp", data=treatment)
cplot(reg3, x="total_imp", data=control, color="blue")
```

I'd love to have these in the same axis.

I am kind of new to R - so sorry for the naivete.

Comment: In the second call to `cplot()`, add this: `draw = "add"`. This will combine the plots.

Comment: You may want to add specific colors, so you know which is which, too. This will work: `col = "blue"` in one, `col = "red"` in the other.